# Vanmoof bottom bracket sensor

Tags: bottom-bracket, sensor

I have a Vanmoof S2 and had the bottom bracket replaced ~6months ago. Now I experienced cutout of the motor again and recently no support at all.
I disassembled the bike and found no signs of wear of the bracket but I am unable to troubleshoot the issue.
I see that the bracket has 3 wires (red, black, green) with +5V between red/black. From.the old bracket I have the cable.

Is there any way that I can stimulate the wires to simulate a working bracket - to confirm the issue?
Any help or suggestions are welcome!